# Allow access from 192.168.1.* to 192.168.2.*

Tags: networking, router, routing, subnet, openwrt

My current network setup looks like this:

```
Cable Modem/Router (provided by ISP) ---- Router 1 ----------- Router 2
                                          LAN: 192.168.1.1     LAN: 192.168.2.1
                                          Software: OpenWRT    Software: DD-WRT
```

I want devices connected to Router 1 to be able to access devices on the `192.168.2.*` subnet. `192.168.2.X -> 192.168.1.X` works, but `192.168.1.X -> 192.168.2.X` doesn't.

How should I do this? Keep in mind I'm a bit of a noob

Comment: Why not just use one subnet?  Put router 2 on router 1 LAN to LAN.

Comment: @John I want to seperate my servers from my devices however i still want my servers to be able to access devices on router 2.

Comment: Why make it so complicated?  You can put servers in the static section and DHCP for your devices.  Even companies do this.

Comment: A router creates a new network. What you want is not doable in this setup. Create one large network, and use subnetmask 255.255.254.0 and you will have both ranges. If you don't want a device to see those of the other range, give that device subnet mask 255.255.255.0, but do note that if a user knows what they do, they could undo it. Alternative is to use a vlan, but in any case, you need all devices to see eachother to start with.

Comment: I agree with LPChip’s suggestions, but since you are new at this I suggest IP ranges (static and dynamic) to sort out your devices AND allow the connectivity you desire

Comment: @LPChip `What you want is not doable in this setup.` Except it is. With the fact that *Router 2* is a WRT (Linux) router, he can literally configure firewall rules to add some protection for his servers (under Router 1) from his devices (under Router 2). (Although I do admit that it's hard to tell what he was thinking when he said `separate`.)

Comment: @TomYan if you put router 2 WAN port in router 1 LAN port, as he stated that he did (otherwise you can't get this configuration to work), you can't really make router 1 see the devices of router 2.

Comment: @LPChip It depends on what you mean by "see". It's true that they won't be in the same broadcast domain, but if you are talking about (S)NAT, then no, it won't prevent the "outer" devices from *reaching* (including receiving "recognizable" replies from) the "inner" ones, since in *at least* Linux(WRT), (S)NAT is stateful. All it takes is an indirect route (and *corresponding filtering* in the firewall of router 2 is down). See Albin's answer and my comment there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Your current problem is the following (in layman's terms):**

Router 2 sends all destination IPs outside of 192.168.2.0/24 (or with whatever subnet mask you are using, I assume it's 24 bits) to router 1. And router 1, being part of the subnet, knows how to handle them. It basically knows what to send to the LAN and what to send to the cable modem and out to the internet. That's why it works.

But router 1 sends all destination IPs outside of 192.168.1.0/24 (or with whatever subnet mask you are using, again I assume it's 24 bits) to your cable modem, but the cable modem doesn't really know what to do with them. It sends them "out to the internet" where they - of course - don't have any destination. That's why it doesn't work.

**The solution (again in layman's terms):**

You need to set the appropriate static route in router 1 so it routes the 192.168.2.0/24 destinations to Router 2 instead of the cable modem. But make sure it's only 192.168.2.0/24 that goes to router 2, the rest (usually 0.0.0.0) should still go to the cable modem. Otherwise, your internet access won't work anymore.

There are tons of step-by-step howtos on how to add static routes (if your router supports this), if you have trouble implementing the static route, let us know and add the appropriate information to your question.

Comment: He'll need to make sure the firewall on router 2 allows such traffics as well. Might also need configure DHCP reservation on router 1 for router 2('s "WAN IP"). (Or set a static WAN IP that is in the subnet but not in the DHCP range of router 1's LAN on router 2)

Comment: Thanks! This worked perfectly fine after allowing traffic from 192.168.2.0/24 using iptables

Comment: @Sam glad to help, please don't forget to mark the answer as accepted